# Error trying to use IntelliJ IDE Database Spark Connector

Tags: apache-spark, intellij-idea

I try to use the `IntelliJ -> Database -> New -> Other -> Spark Connector`

The issue is that after selecting the option, I get the exception shared at the end of the question.

I can not find documentation about the right way to use it, so I suppose that I'm doing something wrong.

How to fix it or where is the documentation or step-by-step tutorial or whatever that can help?

```
IntelliJ IDEA 2022.1.1 (Ultimate Edition)
Build #IU-221.5591.52, built on May 10, 2022
Licensed to XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
Subscription is active until January 3, 2023.
Runtime version: 11.0.14.1+1-b2043.45 amd64
VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o.
Linux 5.15.0-33-generic
GC: G1 Young Generation, G1 Old Generation
Memory: 4096M
Cores: 16
Registry:
    ide.balloon.shadow.size=0
    scala.erase.compiler.process.jdk.once=false

Non-Bundled Plugins:
    Key Promoter X (2022.1.2)
    com.4lex4.intellij.solarized (2.4.0)
    com.arcticicestudio.nord.jetbrains (0.13.0)
    com.intellij.javafx (1.0.4)
    com.intellij.nativeDebug (221.5591.54)
    com.intellij.plugins.gnomekeymap (213.4250.391)
    com.intellij.plugins.xwinkeymap (211.4961.30)
    com.markskelton.one-dark-theme (5.6.0)
    commit-template-idea-plugin (1.2.0)
    de.docs_as_co.intellij.plugin.diagramsnet (0.1.12)
    net.seesharpsoft.intellij.plugins.csv (2.18.2)
    org.antlr.intellij.plugin (1.19.2)
    org.intellij.plugins.hcl (221.5591.19)
    org.jetbrains.plugins.rest (221.5591.19)
    name.kropp.intellij.makefile (221.5591.19)
    AWSCloudFormation (221.5591.19)
    com.intellij.kubernetes (221.5591.58)
    org.jetbrains.plugins.ruby (221.5591.52)
    org.nik.presentation-assistant (1.0.9)
    org.tbm98.flutter-riverpod-snippets (2.221.0)
    org.rust.lang (0.4.170.4627-221)
    org.sonarlint.idea (6.7.0.45926)
    com.intellij.guice (221.5591.19)
    org.jetbrains.plugins.hocon (2022.1.0)
    org.asciidoctor.intellij.asciidoc (0.37.19)
    com.jetbrains.lang.ejs (221.5591.19)
    mdx.js (1.0.221)
    Dart (221.5591.58)
    com.localizely.flutter-intl (1.17.3-2020.3)
    io.flutter (67.1.4)
    org.intellij.scala (2022.1.15)
    zielu.gittoolbox (212.9.0)
    Pythonid (221.5591.52)
    com.github.shiraji.yaemoji (1.0.7)
    com.intellij.bigdatatools (221.4165.63)
    ru.adelf.idea.dotenv (2022.1)
    aws.toolkit (1.43-221)
    com.intellij.plugins.html.instantEditing (221.5591.19)

Kotlin: 221-1.6.21-release-337-IJ5591.52
Current Desktop: ubuntu:GNOME
```

This is the exception that I get just after clicking:

```
java.lang.AbstractMethodError: Receiver class com.intellij.bigdatatools.zeppelin.ztools.database.introspector.ZeppelinSparkIntrospector$Factory does not define or inherit an implementation of the resolved method 'abstract boolean supportsMultilevelIntrospection()' of interface com.intellij.database.introspection.DBIntrospector$Factory.
    at com.intellij.database.introspection.DBIntrospectorFeatures.supportsMultilevelIntrospection(DBIntrospectorFeatures.kt:11)
    at com.intellij.database.view.ui.DatabaseDriverOptionsPanel.<init>(DatabaseDriverOptionsPanel.java:82)
    at com.intellij.database.view.ui.DatabaseDriverConfigurable.createComponent(DatabaseDriverConfigurable.java:78)
    at com.intellij.database.view.ui.SidePanelItem.createConfigurable(SidePanelItem.java:131)
    at com.intellij.database.view.ui.DatabaseConfigEditorImpl.createEditorIfNeeded(DatabaseConfigEditorImpl.java:582)
    at com.intellij.database.view.ui.DatabaseConfigEditorImpl.setSelectedEditor(DatabaseConfigEditorImpl.java:593)
    at com.intellij.database.view.ui.DatabaseConfigEditorImpl.navigateTo(DatabaseConfigEditorImpl.java:376)
    at com.intellij.database.view.ui.DatabaseConfigEditorImpl.navigateTo(DatabaseConfigEditorImpl.java:699)
    at com.intellij.database.view.ui.DatabaseConfigSideTab.lambda$createSidePanel$2(DatabaseConfigSideTab.java:125)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.JList.fireSelectionValueChanged(JList.java:1804)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.JList$ListSelectionHandler.valueChanged(JList.java:1818)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.DefaultListSelectionModel.fireValueChanged(DefaultListSelectionModel.java:219)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.DefaultListSelectionModel.fireValueChanged(DefaultListSelectionModel.java:186)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.DefaultListSelectionModel.setValueIsAdjusting(DefaultListSelectionModel.java:723)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.JList.setValueIsAdjusting(JList.java:2152)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicListUI$Handler.mouseReleased(BasicListUI.java:2958)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.mouseReleased(AWTEventMulticaster.java:298)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.mouseReleased(AWTEventMulticaster.java:297)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.mouseReleased(AWTEventMulticaster.java:297)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.mouseReleased(AWTEventMulticaster.java:297)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.mouseReleased(AWTEventMulticaster.java:297)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6654)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3345)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6419)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2263)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:5029)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2321)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4861)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4918)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4547)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4488)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2307)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2793)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4861)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:778)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:727)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:721)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:85)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:95)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$5.run(EventQueue.java:751)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$5.run(EventQueue.java:749)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:85)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:748)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.defaultDispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:898)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchMouseEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:820)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue._dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:743)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.lambda$dispatchEvent$6(IdeEventQueue.java:439)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.computePrioritized(CoreProgressManager.java:803)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.lambda$dispatchEvent$7(IdeEventQueue.java:438)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.TransactionGuardImpl.performActivity(TransactionGuardImpl.java:106)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.performActivity(IdeEventQueue.java:604)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.lambda$dispatchEvent$8(IdeEventQueue.java:436)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.runIntendedWriteActionOnCurrentThread(ApplicationImpl.java:873)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:484)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:207)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:128)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:121)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport$2.run(WaitDispatchSupport.java:190)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport$4.run(WaitDispatchSupport.java:235)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport$4.run(WaitDispatchSupport.java:233)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport.enter(WaitDispatchSupport.java:233)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:1070)
    at com.intellij.openapi.ui.impl.DialogWrapperPeerImpl$MyDialog.show(DialogWrapperPeerImpl.java:702)
    at com.intellij.openapi.ui.impl.DialogWrapperPeerImpl.show(DialogWrapperPeerImpl.java:439)
    at com.intellij.openapi.ui.DialogWrapper.doShow(DialogWrapper.java:1668)
    at com.intellij.openapi.ui.DialogWrapper.show(DialogWrapper.java:1626)
    at com.intellij.database.view.ui.DataSourceManagerDialog.showDialog(DataSourceManagerDialog.java:104)
    at com.intellij.database.view.ui.DataSourceManagerDialog.showDialog(DataSourceManagerDialog.java:79)
    at com.intellij.database.view.ui.DataSourceManagerDialog.showDialog(DataSourceManagerDialog.java:73)
    at com.intellij.database.actions.DatabaseViewActions$AddDriver.actionPerformed(DatabaseViewActions.java:274)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.ex.ActionUtil.lambda$performActionDumbAwareWithCallbacks$4(ActionUtil.java:235)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.ex.ActionUtil.performDumbAwareWithCallbacks(ActionUtil.java:256)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.ex.ActionUtil.performActionDumbAwareWithCallbacks(ActionUtil.java:235)
    at com.intellij.ui.popup.ActionPopupStep.performAction(ActionPopupStep.java:240)
    at com.intellij.ui.popup.ActionPopupStep.performAction(ActionPopupStep.java:249)
    at com.intellij.ui.popup.ActionPopupStep.performAction(ActionPopupStep.java:245)
    at com.intellij.ui.popup.ActionPopupStep.lambda$onChosen$1(ActionPopupStep.java:220)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.TransactionGuardImpl.performActivity(TransactionGuardImpl.java:106)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.TransactionGuardImpl.performUserActivity(TransactionGuardImpl.java:95)
    at com.intellij.ui.popup.AbstractPopup.lambda$dispose$18(AbstractPopup.java:1538)
    at com.intellij.util.ui.EdtInvocationManager.invokeLaterIfNeeded(EdtInvocationManager.java:101)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.ifFocusEventsInTheQueue(IdeEventQueue.java:179)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.executeWhenAllFocusEventsLeftTheQueue(IdeEventQueue.java:132)
    at com.intellij.openapi.wm.impl.FocusManagerImpl.doWhenFocusSettlesDown(FocusManagerImpl.java:172)
    at com.intellij.ui.popup.AbstractPopup.dispose(AbstractPopup.java:1535)
    at com.intellij.ui.popup.WizardPopup.dispose(WizardPopup.java:162)
    at com.intellij.ui.popup.list.ListPopupImpl.dispose(ListPopupImpl.java:326)
    at com.intellij.ui.popup.PopupFactoryImpl$ActionGroupPopup.dispose(PopupFactoryImpl.java:272)
    at com.intellij.openapi.util.ObjectTree.runWithTrace(ObjectTree.java:139)
    at com.intellij.openapi.util.ObjectTree.executeAll(ObjectTree.java:169)
    at com.intellij.openapi.util.Disposer.dispose(Disposer.java:219)
    at com.intellij.openapi.util.Disposer.dispose(Disposer.java:207)
    at com.intellij.ui.popup.WizardPopup.disposeAllParents(WizardPopup.java:266)
    at com.intellij.ui.popup.list.ListPopupImpl.handleNextStep(ListPopupImpl.java:434)
    at com.intellij.ui.popup.list.ListPopupImpl._handleSelect(ListPopupImpl.java:406)
    at com.intellij.ui.popup.list.ListPopupImpl.handleSelect(ListPopupImpl.java:361)
    at com.intellij.ui.popup.PopupFactoryImpl$ActionGroupPopup.handleSelect(PopupFactoryImpl.java:289)
    at com.intellij.ui.popup.list.ListPopupImpl$MyMouseListener.mouseReleased(ListPopupImpl.java:618)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.mouseReleased(AWTEventMulticaster.java:298)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6654)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3345)
    at com.intellij.ui.popup.list.ListPopupImpl$MyList.processMouseEvent(ListPopupImpl.java:694)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6419)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2263)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:5029)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2321)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4861)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4918)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4547)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4488)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2307)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2793)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4861)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:778)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:727)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:721)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:85)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:95)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$5.run(EventQueue.java:751)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$5.run(EventQueue.java:749)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:85)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:748)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.defaultDispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:898)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchMouseEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:820)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue._dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:743)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.lambda$dispatchEvent$6(IdeEventQueue.java:439)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.computePrioritized(CoreProgressManager.java:803)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.lambda$dispatchEvent$7(IdeEventQueue.java:438)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.TransactionGuardImpl.performActivity(TransactionGuardImpl.java:119)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.performActivity(IdeEventQueue.java:604)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.lambda$dispatchEvent$8(IdeEventQueue.java:436)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.runIntendedWriteActionOnCurrentThread(ApplicationImpl.java:873)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:484)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:207)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:128)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:117)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:113)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:92)
```

Comment: Try disabling big data tools plugin. Does it help?

Comment: @KonstantinAnnikov Working when Big Tools Plugin is disabled. Why?

Comment: there is its trace in the error you attached. Please create a bug for the plugin